# Extending a docker image to run a diff command

Tags: docker

I have a docker file as below.

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8/ubi

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/zulu11
RUN \
    set -xeu && \
    yum -y -q install https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu-repo-1.0.0-1.noarch.rpm && \
    yum -y -q install python3 zulu11-jdk less && \
    yum -q clean all && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/yum && \
    alternatives --set python /usr/bin/python3 && \
    groupadd trino --gid 1000 && \
    useradd trino --uid 1000 --gid 1000 && \
    mkdir -p /usr/lib/trino /data/trino && \
    chown -R "trino:trino" /usr/lib/trino /data/trino

ARG TRINO_VERSION
COPY trino-cli-${TRINO_VERSION}-executable.jar /usr/bin/trino
COPY --chown=trino:trino trino-server-${TRINO_VERSION} /usr/lib/trino
COPY --chown=trino:trino default/etc /etc/trino

EXPOSE 8080
USER trino:trino
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
CMD ["/usr/lib/trino/bin/run-trino"]
HEALTHCHECK --interval=10s --timeout=5s --start-period=10s \
  CMD /usr/lib/trino/bin/health-check
```

I would like to extend this Dockerfile and run a run a couple of instructions before running the main command in the Dockerfile? Not sure how to to that.

Comment: You can add many commands before `CMD`. Did you try that? Also why do you have two `CMD`s?

Comment: This is 3rd party Docker file. I need to extend and run few more command before the actual command

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand your meaning. You can have multiple commands, then `docker` will detect the last `CMD` and runs it in the last stage even if `CMD` is not in the last line.

Comment: I have a 3rd party Docker image with a command and would like to extend the Image so that I can include few more stuff and run the final command in the parent Docker image.

Comment: @Saeed the second CMD is a parameter to the healthcheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run those commands when the container starts, you can use an entrypoint to leave the original command untouched.

The `exec $@` will execute the arguments that were passed to the entrypoint with PID 1. Whatever arguments were provided as `CMD`, those will be in `$@`, so you essentially execute the `CMD` after the `ENTRYPOINT`, doesn't matter what this command might be.

Create an entrypoint script:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh
# run some preperation
exec "$@"
```

And then you copy that into your build and use it.

```
FROM baseimage
COPY --chmod=755 ./entrypoint.sh /
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
```

---

If you want to run those commands on build, use a `FROM` instruction and add your `RUN` instructions. The new image will use the `CMD` from the base image. So you don't need to set any `CMD`.

```
FROM baseimage
RUN more
RUN stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you can only have one CMD statement in a Dockerfile (if you have more than one, only the last one is executed), you need to get all your commands into a single CMD statement.

You can use the ability of the shell to chain commands using the `&&` operator, like this

```
CMD my-first-command && \
    my-second-command && \
    /usr/lib/trino/bin/run-trino
```

That will run your commands first before running `run-trino` which is the current CMD.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are using a base image, docker throw's away the last layer of the image. So you can extend that image, by writing your own image.

for example: this is my first image (that i get from a third party, just like you)

```
FROM alpine:latest
CMD echo "hello"
```

I want to extend it, to output hello world instead of hello, so I extend write another docker file like this

```
FROM first:latest
CMD echo "hello world"
```

and when I build the image and run it,

```
docker build -t second .
docker run second
```

I get my expected output

```
hello world
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: Docker keeps all of the layers of the base image, but only the last `CMD` you write (in either the base or derived image) has an effect.  So the extended Dockerfile works because its `CMD` overrides the base image's `CMD`.